# Windows 10 problem with GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

I've had a dual boot windows 10-Ubuntu for a couple of months, and yesterday out of nowhere i saw that i can't boot into my Windows. Grub is not detecting it.

Over this months i had similar problems, but running

```
sudo update-grub
```

and with help of boot repair, i was able to fix those problems. But now it is different, running boot repair, an error message appears saying:

> LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB).

The thing is, when I installed ubuntu, I checked that it was with the same boot method as Windows (both on UEFI, i think). Otherwise, the dual boot would never have been able to work all of this time.

Here's a list of things that I already tried:

- Running sudo update-grub
- Running repair boot
- Check if fast boot and secure boot are disabled in my BIOS
- Disabling CSM in my BIOS

And nothing worked.
The folder  /sys/firmware/efi/ exists in my Ubuntu, so I assume that now is on UEFI mode. Running `sudo os-prober` returns nothing (even with all of the disks mounted).

I'm pretty noob with ubuntu, sorry if I said something dumb. Can Windows turn into Legacy boot out of nowhere?. I generated a paste bin from boot repair, in case that may help:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vq3HnH9xSS/

Comment: *"Can Windows turn into Legacy boot out of nowhere"* - This is a question for the Windows community, but I think the answer is probably "No". In any case, Ubuntu and Windows must both be installed in the same mode or else you'll encounter problems with dual boot configuration and GRUB. If Windows is CSM and Ubuntu is EFI you'll need to change one of them, preferably switching Windows to EFI. Unfortunately this generally requires reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Grub does not use boot flag, Windows has to have boot flag on its partition with boot files. But not sure if your Windows is booting from sda1 or sdb1. And then you cannot have an ESP - efi system partition on same drive as it also needs boot,esp flags. Move boot flag back to sdb1 with gparted or Windows. Better to have grub in MBR of one drive and Windows boot loader in the other. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode. Best to have both systems in UEFI mode as Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. But conversion from MBR to gpt will erase entire drive. Backups required.